# Carrier Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wan, metro-ethernet

On my courses slide there is a chapter about this concept. I thought it was some sort of idea about replacing legacy and non-flexible technologies as SONET and so on in favor of Ethernet family technologies.

Am i wrong to assume that Carrier Ethernet networks are a sort of enlargement of the LAN Ethernet networks used for deploying MANs and WANs? Can it be seen as the idea of covering a wide area, providing different services (with different bandwidths and needs) to different organizations, using the Ethernet family technologies?

Answer (score 2):

"Carrier Ethernet" provides WAN PHYs - point-to-point and passive optical networks (PON) - as well as some extensions to the basic Ethernet concept for carrier use, including QinQ/VLAN stacking, virtual private lines/LANs/trees, and compatibility to legacy networks (SDH/SONET) or general MPLS services.

Carrier Ethernet is designed to coexist with (virtual) circuit switched networks to enable a smooth transition.